# WinJS/IE 10 IndexedDB throws incorrect exception when opening with a version of 0

Tags: exception, w3c, winjs, indexeddb, internet-explorer-10

According to the latest version of the [w3 spec for indexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#database-api), a call to `indexedDB.open` with a version of < 1 e.g. `window.indexedDB.open('somename', 0)` should have the following behavior:

> DOMException   TypeError  The value of version is 0 (zero) or a negative
>   number.

However, I've noticed that WinJS seemingly throws the wrong exception of the type `InvalidStateError`.

Am I misunderstanding the w3 spec, or is this a defect in the (I'm assuming it's the IE10 engine) implementation?

The reason I'm calling this out is because it took me a while to connect the error I was seeing (`InvalidState`) with my code using an invalid version number - hopefully others will be able to avoid my mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't open a database with version 0. It needs to be at least 1 or Higher. The spec says:

> When a database is first created, its version is 0.

So when you are trying to open a database that doesn't exist yet, it will be created and get the version 0. After the database is created, the onupgradeneeded method will be called so you can define your structure. In here you will see that the oldversion is 0 and the newversion the provided version or 1 (if you didn't provide a version.)

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that -- the question is regarding the exception that is thrown when you do attempt to call .open('foo', **0**) -- it throws a different exception than the spec says it should

Comment: That is possible, IE 10 doesn't completely implement the spec as discribed. Things like the unique attribute on object store and the multi entry functionality on the index is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It seemed that this is a pretty important behavior violation of the spec, which is why I thought it a defect. I wasn't aware of some of the missing functionality -- unique constraint would seem to me to be A Big Deal To Have, no? Can you explain what you mean by 'multi entry functionality on the index is missing'? Does it mean that you can't have multiple indices on an object store or that you can't have a single indice comprised of composite properties?

Comment: If this behavior is a defect, would it be helpful for me to file an issue on it?

Comment: The unique functionality is implemented in IE, I was mistaking, but it is the autoIncrement attribute that you can't consult. The functionality is present but not the attribute to check it afterwards For the multiEntry part: In ie you can't turn multiEntry on so you can search inside an array if an index is placed on an array. It will just behave as an normal index

Comment: gotcha - I appreciate the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with IE10. What I did to get it going was to use the prefix 'msIndexedDB' AND...the open function takes the DB name as is ONLY parameter. So, they have reverted to using the deprecated version of open. I have no idea why that makes good software engineering sense to them as it makes less than none to me.